# ArcGIS JS - Execute won't run

Tags: javascript, execute, esri, arcgis-js-api

This is mostly a follow-up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766736/arcgis-api-execute-querytask-unsupported).
I am using the ArcGIS javascript API. I need to run queries in order to select the object that the user just clicked. When the layer is clicked, the query should run. The execute method is now recognised, but does not work as it should. It should process the query and call a function 'Selectie', which has the parameter 'featureSet' added to it by execute, as explained [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_querytask.html).
The function never runs though, whatever it contains. The relevant code:

```
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4");

        thema_4_Verblijf = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4");
        map_Thema_4.addLayer(thema_4_Verblijf);
        thema_4_Verblijf.on("click", thema_4_Verblijf_Click);

        function thema_4_Verblijf_Click(evt){
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = ["*"];
            query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
            executeQuery();
        };

        function executeQuery()
        {
            queryTask.execute(query,Selectie);
        }

        function Selectie(featureSet){
            alert("function called");
        }
```

This problem has my totally blocked from making any progress, and the only alternative I can think of now is manually creating polygons with the required data, which will obviously be an extreme waste of time, considering this query could achieve the same thing, if it worked.